# Qual a diferença entre executar o programa no emulador e num dispositivo físico?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou iniciando os estudos no desenvolvimento android com o Android Studio e gostaria de saber se é possível criar aplicações apenas executando o código em um dispositivo físico ou se é necessário emular outros dispositivos para evitar erros e etc.

O emulador do Android Studio roda com dificuldade na minha máquina, então preciso saber se ele é imprescindível para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos ou se existem outras alternativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você nunca erra se preferir executar seu app sempre no dispositivo físico.

Os emuladores Android são lentos e não implementam todos os dispositivos. Por exemplo, simular GPS, câmera, sensores... tudo isso não funciona ou não funciona de forma realista no emulador.

A situação não é muito diferente no iOS, exceto que os emuladores são mais rápidos.

Os emuladores servem para fazer testes unitários, e para ver o que acontece com seu programa ao rodar numa versão específica do Android. Pessoalmente eu uso para testar o app em versões muito antigas, ou tão novas que nenhum celular ainda tem.

Para testar seus apps, tente usar um aparelho razoavelmente recente, que esteja recebendo atualizações (e rode Android 11). Se precisar suportar uma gama de versões do Android, arrume também um aparelho mais velho, tipo Android 7.